# How to parse variable code, contained within a string, as if it were part of the python script

Tags: python, string, variables, eval

The root question is how to take something that is stored (elsewhere/earlier) as a string containing un-translated variables and force python to re-evaluate it so that the variables written within the string can be converted to their now-known values.

I have a variable that is defined something like (there are multiple versions of this variable possible):

```
src_check = "SELECT daily_installs FROM mr_app WHERE report_date = '\" + row[0] + \"' AND country = '\" + row[3] + \"'"
```

I'm using the \" because at that moment, the variable for row is unknown. However, I can't figure out how to convert it back into literal code, later, so that I can do something like this (after the needed variables are defined of course):

```
cursor.execute(code_version_of_src_check)
```

I have tried:

```
cursor.execute(src_check.replace("\"",""))
```

but it does not process row as a variable.

This is one example of a problem I keep running into and haven't found a good solution for. For another example, the initial variable strings would be pulled from a database table and could be something like:

```
"/partitions/" + dateToCheck.strftime('%Y-%m-%d/')
```

This would need to get converted into something like "/partitions/2016-06-21/", with `dateToCheck` being defined within the Python script that pulls from the DB. This particular example is for a monitor. There are hundreds of rows, and they have a variety of variables within this data field, with the value of the date-related ones changing constantly.

I tried using [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) as well, but couldn't get it to work and it was hard to find examples for it when everyone just says "don't use it" for reasons that aren't applicable here (no outside input/users involved).

(Using Python 2.7.6)

Answer (score 0):

That is what functions are for.

```
def get_src_check(row):
  return "SELECT daily_installs FROM mr_app WHERE report_date = '" + row[0] + "' AND country = '" + row[3] + "'"

....

row = ...
cursor.execute(get_src_check(row))
```

Comment: I think I'm not making part of this clear. What src_check is, is not always the same. There are many different versions of src_check that can be processed, and there are many different rows for each src_check. I can't write a function for each one. Perhaps this is more clear with the second example, where I'm pulling the string from a database table - that table has hundreds of rows and each string may or may not use one or more variables that come from the main script.

Answer (score 0):

You can run cursor.execute with string variable.

from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()

src_check = str("SELECT daily_installs FROM mr_app WHERE report_date ='" + row[0] + "' AND country = '" + row[3] + "'")

cursor.execute(src_check)

row = cursor.fetchone()

You can find good examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, so I edited it to try and make it more clear. Also, row is an array that has been defined in between the src_check definition and the cursor.execute.